# Send an XML file via POST

Tags: php, xml, post, http-post

I am developing a web application with PHP in order to interact with IP phones. I need to send an XML file to an IP address via POST. Can you please tell me how I can send below information using PHP to a certain IP address?

POST / HTTP/1.1
    Host: 192.168.1.101:8088
    User-Agent: Go 1.1 package http
    Content-Length: 483
    Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hotel>
<command cmd="checkin" />
<guestinfo>
<Name>Hoss Astaraki</Name>
<SuiteNumber>7500</SuiteNumber>
<PhoneNumber>4166377500</PhoneNumber>
</guestinfo>
<MemoryKey>
<Key name="Del Suite" number="1234" />
<Key name="Guest Service" number="1235" />
<Key name="Housekeeping" number="1236" />
<Key name="Building Security" number="1237" />
<Key name="Helpdesk" number="1238" />
<Key name="Front Desk" number="1239" />
</MemoryKey>
</hotel>
```

Comment: [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) comes to mind

Comment: Can you give me an example how I can send this XML message to an IP address with using CURL?

Comment: Don't ask, just search :) - Please see the duplicate and from that one on, you should find other linked resources about the topic.